# Remove white space between the string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string. I just want to remove all white spaces between all characters.Please reply 
"PB 10 CV 2662" to "PB10CV2662"

Comment: `str=str.split(" ").join();`

Comment: @anikt that goes in an answer not a comment.

Comment: Do you want to remove new lines as well (if there are any) between characters? How about white spaces at start and end that **not between characters** ?

Comment: @anubhava That's exactly what we need to know, great way to word the question!

Comment: @bugwheels94 ```str=str.split(" ").join();``` should be ```str=str.split(" ").join('')```;
your version adds comma in between

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = "PB 10 CV 2662";
str = str.replace(/ +/g, "");
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
var s = "PB 10 CV 2662";
s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

OR

```
s.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Comment: and then you replace all whitespace with... a whitespace :)

Comment: This is faulty answer, 1. It removes new lines also and 2. It puts whitespace back so OP's string will remain "as is".

Comment: @anubhava in this question there is no specification like new line should be remain as it is. the user just wanna remove the whitespace from his string my answer is for that only.

Comment: True but your substitute string is a space, which is **wrong**

Answer (score 7):

```
var str = "PB 10 CV 2662"; 
str = str.split(" ") //[ 'PB', '10', 'CV', '2662' ]
str = str.join("") // 'PB10CV2662'

OR in one line:
str = str.split(" ").join("")
```

Comment: this only removes the first white space

Answer (score 5):

### 2022 - use `replaceAll`

Most of these answers were done before the [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method was implemented.

Now you can simply do:

```
let str = "PB 10 CV 2662";
str = str.replaceAll(' ', '');
```

Which will replace all instances and is much more readable than the regex to make the `.replace` a global-replace on a target.

Comment: @Gel which browser are you using? It works just fine in Chrome latest. Can you post your code?

Comment: max  some reason it didnt work a while back.  Its working! Deleting that comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the `replace()` method for strings:

```
var stringVal = "PB 10 CV 2662";
var newStringVal = stringVal.replace(/ /g, "");
```

That will take the current string value and create a new one where all of the spaces are replaced by empty strings.

Comment: This only replaces the **first** `" "` occurrence

Comment: @anubhava `replace` expects a string **or** regex

Comment: @Ian Yeah, I know . . . it's late here . . . not thinking straight.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "PB 10 CV 2662";
var cleaned = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");
```

Comment: `\s` targets more than just spaces

Comment: This will remove new lines as well.

Comment: @anubhava Actually, I realized the OP said `I just want to remove all white spaces`, so technically this is correct. My first comment was wrong. Although it should use `+`. Even if the example only has spaces

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, I edited my comment and mentioned it should use `+`. My main point was that the target should be `\s`, not `[ ]`, based solely on the fact that the OP said "all white spaces", even if the example only uses spaces. I'm betting the OP really only needs to target `[ ]`, but who knows

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg I hope it's okay - I just edited your answer too. Simply calling `str.replace()` doesn't modify the string in place (strings are immutable)...it returns a new string. So it needs to be assigned to something. And your example used `string.replace`, but the variable was `str`, so I just changed that too

Comment: @Ian: I saw your edit and removed my comment. However yes I agree that OP isn't very clear as per `white spaces between all characters` it might mean white spaces at start/end shouldn't be removed also, who knows...

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg Don't feel stupid! It's just a simple example and had a small typo. Hopefully it looks better/complete :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let text = "space    is    short  but      tab   is  long"
let arr = text.split(" ").filter(x => x !== "")
let finalText = "";

for (let item of arr) {
  finalText += item + " "
}

console.log(finalText)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let str1="Lorem    Ipsum is simply       dummy text of    the printing and typesetting     industry.";
    let str1Arr = str1.split(" ");
    str1Arr = str1Arr.filter(item => {
        if (item !== " ")
            return item;
    })
    str1 = str1Arr.join(" ");
    console.log(str1);
```

We can remove spaces in between the string or template string by splitting the string into array.
After that filter out the text element and skip element having space.
And Finally, join the array to string with single spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var sample_str =  "PB 10 CV 2662" 
var new_str = sample_str.split(" ").join("")
```

Or you could use `.replace` with the global flag like so:

```
   var sample_str =  "PB 10 CV 2662" 
   var new_str = sample_str.replace(" ","","g")
```

Both will result in new_str being equal to  "PB10CV2662".
Hope this is of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

**should not allowed to add space in the end or in between use**
`replaceAll(' ', '') instead of trim()`.

> onChangeText={value => onChange(value.replaceAll(' ', ''))}

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

```
value = value.replace(/(\r\n\s|\n|\r|\s)/gm, '');
```